Mishkan vs Ohel Moed
What is the difference between the Mishkan and Ohel Moed? These two terms come up in Chumash and I often conflate them.

This question is addressed in an article on Parshat Vayakhel/Pekudei entitled The Sanctuary by Rabbi Bernie Fox.
Rabbi Fox poses the question as follows

Bnai Yisrael were commanded to construct a sanctuary that would
accompany them in the wilderness. The Chumash provides a detailed
description of this sanctuary and its contents. In the above passage,
Moshe is commanded to assemble and erect the completed sanctuary. The
passage employs two terms in referring to this sanctuary. It is
referred to it as Mishcan – Tabernacle – and as Ohel Moed – Tent of
Meeting. What is the difference between these two terms? Both seem to
refer to the single sanctuary! Why are both terms needed?

and at the end of his article having considered various sources in detail Rabbi Fox concludes:

Now, our original question is easily answered. The terms Mishcan and
Ohel Moed both refer to the sanctuary. However, these terms refer to
different aspects of the structure. Mishcan is the innermost
structure. The innermost curtains create this structure. Ohel Moed –
tent of meeting – refers to the middle curtains that create the tent
within, where the Mishcan is situated.


Mishkan Ha'edes- because that is where the Torah/Luchos were stored, i.e. in the Kodesh Hakodoshim.
Ohel Moed is the tented covering that included the Menorah, Mizbeach Hazahav, and the Shulchan.
Just adding to previous answer.
